# Add multiple value obtained from spinner in CardView together

Tags: android, arrays, android-spinner, android-cardview

I have a CardView containing a spinner. The spinner contains number from 0 to 5 for user to choose. Each CardView itself has a unique ID associated with it. For example say that now I have two cards, card A with ID of 1 and card B with ID of 2. Depending on the value selected from the spinner I will create an array. For example card A has value of 3 and card B has value of 2, the final array will then look like [1,1,1,2,2], and if the spinner of the value of card A is changed to 0, then the array will be updated to [2,2].
I can now create separated array for each cards, but I am not sure how to add the arrays together or update the arrays based on the final values in each spinners

What I have now:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final ChooseServiceList chooseServiceList1 =  chooseServiceList.get(position);

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<Integer> categories = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    categories.add(0);
    categories.add(1);
    categories.add(2);
    categories.add(3);
    categories.add(4);
    categories.add(5);

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    holder.spinnerServiceNum.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    holder.spinnerServiceNum.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            Integer serviceCount = Integer.parseInt(item);//spinner value
            Integer serviceId = chooseServiceList1.getServiceId();//ID associated with card
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int service = 1; service<=serviceCount; service++) {
                list.add(serviceId);
                if(service == serviceCount){
                    //final numbers of each ID that should be add into array
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            //do nothing
        }
    });
}
```

I can print out the separate arrays now e.g. [1,1,1], [2,2], but how should I update and combine them after spinner is selected? I tried putting them in a shared preference but this will only make the final array [2,2] the shared preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the list definition final and move it to the outer class. So remove this line...

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And instead, at the top of your code, write...

```
final ChooseServiceList chooseServiceList1 =  chooseServiceList.get(position);
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```